# Merge 2 select from 2 table without relationships

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a search engine in php and i use Mysql . I'm trying to search into 2 different kind of tables.A blog table and categories table.

I can't use UNION because tables doesn't have the same number of columns.

```
SELECT titre, description,url,'actualites' AS type 
FROM cs_actualites 
WHERE cs_actualites.description LIKE :pattern
OR cs_actualites.titre LIKE  :pattern

SELECT
root.url           rootUrl,
parent.url         parentUrl,
child.url          childUrl,
parent.titre       parentTitle,
parent.description parentDesc,
child.titre        childTitle,
child.description  childDesc
FROM cs_categories root
LEFT JOIN cs_categories parent
 ON root.id = parent.parent
LEFT JOIN cs_categories child
 ON parent.id = child.parent
WHERE (root.description LIKE :pattern OR root.titre LIKE :pattern)
  OR (parent.titre LIKE :pattern OR parent.description LIKE :pattern)
  OR (child.titre LIKE :pattern OR child.description LIKE :pattern);
```

The both queries should results : a title , a description and an url.
The 2nd query should results addionnaly many urls(for each category and sub_category).

How can i get result from those 2 queries into one ?

Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Can you depict your scenario based on some data returned by these two queries?

Comment: show some sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: `SELECT titre, description,url, NULL as parentUrl, NULL as childUrl, ...,'actualites' AS type UNION SELECT NULL, NULL, root.url rootUrl,
parent.url         parentUrl,
child.url          childUrl, ...`  Bring structures to the same mind.

Comment: @Mike thank you , you understood what i was looking for :)